# Css, js and other files can be access but are not applied on the page

Tags: html, jsp, tiles

I made a theme that i use for my web application.
I have included the css, js and other assets on the page. However the page looks as if it's not having any css or any other type of assets on it.

My main template:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
        
        <!-- project css -->
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
        
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/lib/moment.min.js"/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/lib/jquery.min.js"/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"/>"></script>

    </head>
        
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">
           <tiles:insertAttribute name="main"/> 
           <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

In main i insert this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<div id="container-login" class="absolute-center">
    <h2>Login</h2>

    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="errorblock">
            Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
            ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type='text' name='j_username' value='' id="username"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type='password' name='j_password' value='' id="password"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="remember-me"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Log in" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(window).resize(function() {

            $('.absolute-center').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: '50%',
                top: '50%',
                'margin-left': -$('#container-login').width() / 2,
                'margin-top': -$('#container-login').height() / 1.2


            });

        });
        // To initially run the function:
        $(window).resize();

        $('.field-validation-error, .alert').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown');
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

footer is just some text.

When i do view-source in Chrome i can click the corresponding file. It doesnt throw me a 404 and i can view the resource correctly.

i am using spring 3.2.3 with tiles

my tiles configuration:

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
 
<tiles-definitions>
     
    <definition name="base.plain" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/template/basePlain.jsp">
         <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/template/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    
    <definition name="base.main" extends="base.plain">
         <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/template/footer.jsp"/>
         <put-attribute name="main" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/template/base.jsp"/>
    </definition>
     
     
    <definition name="screen.login" extends="base.plain">
        <put-attribute name="main" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/views/login.jsp" />
    </definition>
    
    <definition name="view.planning.viewPlanning" extends="base.main">        
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/planning/viewPlanning.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    
</tiles-definitions>
```

The result:
[image: Result]

Comment: And what does the rsulting markup look like? Could it be that the assets can not be delivierd because no authenticated  session (not logged in) is available?

Comment: I added a picture of the result that i get now.

Comment: What do your web development tools in chrome, firefox or ie say? Are the assets not only loaded, but also have valid content?

Comment: The console is empty, so i assume every asset is correctly delivered. It also says that the assets are delivered

Comment: Yes, but eg. with basic apache wicket (1.4.x), the assets feature the content of  the errorpage for unauthorized access instead of css or js... when the session is not "logged in"... the solution could be to statically mount your assets folder for the login page

Comment: I checked the assets content, they represent the content that i need on that page. It just isn't applied

Comment: Apparently i forgot type="text/css" which solved my issue

Comment: Could you spy what is downloaded from server with a tool like <code>wireshark</code> ?

Answer (score 0):

You refer to your style.css by using `media="print"`
this causes the display problem.
And also explains why chrome shows it as a legal source.